# Which method to define on a Ruby class to provide dup / clone for its instances?

Tags: ruby, clone, dup

I have a `Pointer` class with a single attribute `:contents`, that points to an object of class `MyObject`.

```
class MyObject
  def hello; "hello" end
end

class Pointer
  attr_reader :contents
  def initialize( cont ); @contents = cont end
  # perhaps define some more state
end
```

I want my `Pointer` to be able to make copies of itself. I know that `#dup` method is defined by default, while `#clone` method is expected to be overriden to be able to make deep copies. But here, the copies don't have to be too deep. So, the first dilemma that I have is, should I override `#dup` method, because I don't really want to copy the additional state of my `Pointer`, just make a new one pointing to the same `MyObject` instance? Or should I refrain from overridine `#dup`, because I am not "supposed to" and override `#clone` with a method making shallow copies?

I would welcome comments on the above, but let's say that I will choose to override `#dup`. I could do just this:

```
class Pointer
  def dup; self.class.new( contents ) end
end
```

But online, I read something like "the *dup* method will call the *initialize copy* method". Also, [this guy](http://jonathanleighton.com/articles/2011/initialize_clone-initialize_dup-and-initialize_copy-in-ruby/) writes about `#initialize_clone`, `#initialize_dup` and `#initialize_copy` in Ruby. That leaves me wondering, is the best practice perhaps like this?

```
class Pointer
  def initialize_copy
    # do I don't know what
  end
end
```

Or like this?

```
class Pointer
  def initialize_dup
    # do I don't know what
  end
end
```

Or should I just forget about online rants written to confuse beginners and go for overriding `#dup` without concerns?

Also, I do understand that I can just call `#dup` without defining any custom `#dup`, but what *if* I want to define `#dup` with different behavior?

Also, the same question apply to `#clone` - should I try to define `#initialize_clone` or just `#clone`?

Comment: May I ask why you're making a pointer class at all? Ruby's variables are all already references/pointers.

Comment: Sometimes you want to implement your own data structure or you want the pointer to do tricks. The suject of the question is not whether the class is a pointer or something else, but if you must know, I am interested in Ted Nelson's Zz structures, and Ted defines what he calls "cursors", so I decided to call them "points" like in Emacs. You know, you have to implement the pointer class when the specification of the data structure calls for it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From my experience, overloading #initialize_copy works just fine (never heard about initialize_dup and initialize_clone).

The original initialize_copy (which initializes every instance variable with the values from the original object) is available through super, so I usually do:

```
class MyClass
  def initialize_copy(orig)
    super
    # Do custom initialization for self
  end
end
```

Comment: How does it compare with redefining #dup? Is it ever o.k. to redefine #dup?

Comment: The big difference is that, when you redefine #dup, 'self' is the original object. You therefore don't have access to the new object's internal state. It is the other way around in #initialize_copy

Comment: One more difference: I learned the hard way that, in Matz' Ruby implementation, some C functions call e.g. rb_obj_dup directly instead of using the normal method dispatch. #dup might be one of them. Which means that some standard library stuff would *not* call your version of #dup while it *would* call #initialize_copy

Comment: Oh, and while I am at it, I had a look at the code in MRI. #initialize_dup and #initialize_clone do exist, but only on 1.9.

Comment: Thanks so much. Finally someone clarified this to me.